# Is it normal to defer loading of JQuery with BundleConfig?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am wondering why this may be a good or not so good idea. In our BundleConfig.cs file we have:

```
var jsBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts");

jsBundle.Include("~/Content/JS/jquery.1.11.2.js");
jsBundle.Include("~/Content/JS/bootstrap.3.3.4.js");
jsBundle.Include("~/Content/JS/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js");
jsBundle.Include("~/Content/JS/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js");
jsBundle.Include("~/Content/JS/Script.js");

jsBundle.Orderer = new NonOrderingBundleOrderer();

bundles.Add(jsBundle);
```

This bundle is rendered in our base _Layout view like this:

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")
@Scripts.RenderFormat("<script src='{0}' defer></script>", "~/bundles/scripts")
```

So, if we need to add any javascript I need to add it to one of the scripts in the bundle. Otherwise, because JQuery is defered, the script in my page/view will not run, because it hasn't loaded yet.

I am told that the javascript items are being defered in this project to allow for the page to load without having to wait for the javascript files. Does it make that much of a difference?

Comment: What kind of an answer are you looking for? Whether or not deferring scripts makes a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen that approach before and I would bet that the difference in page load times would be negligible provide the JS files are bundled and minified.

Such an approach also makes it a lot hard to script using Javascript in my opinion